# Not repeating markers in google maps API V3 (JS)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

is it possible to not let the markers repeat horizontally, since I only want the marker to be show on the map, and I am not repeating my map.
As you can see here, it is very anoying:
http://lsres.com/playerdb/test2.php

I currently initialize my map this way:

```
 var map;
  var mapTypeOptions = {
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) { if (coord.y < 0 || coord.y >= 1 << zoom || coord.x < 0 || coord.x >= 1 << zoom){ return "sam/map/samap_a.jpg"; } return "sam/map/samap_"+zoom+"_"+coord.x+"_"+coord.y+".jpg"; },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    maxZoom: 2,
    minZoom: 1,
    name: "Map",
    opacity: 1.0,
    isPng: false,
    alt: "Map"
  }; 

    var satTypeOptions = { 
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) { if (coord.y < 0 || coord.y >= 1 << zoom || coord.x < 0 || coord.x >= 1 << zoom){ return "sam/map/samap_a.jpg"; } return "sam/sat/samap_"+zoom+"_"+coord.x+"_"+coord.y+".jpg"; },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    maxZoom: 2,
    minZoom: 1,
    name: "Satelite"
  };
  var mapMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(mapTypeOptions);
  var satMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(satTypeOptions);

  function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
    var myOptions = {
      center: myLatlng,
      zoom: 1,
      streetViewControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: ["map", "sat"]
      }
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set('map', mapMapType);
    map.mapTypes.set('sat', satMapType);    
    map.setMapTypeId('map');

  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating marker object, set optimized to false, for example:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!',
  optimized: false
});
```

Comment: alternatively, setting draggable: true also works, but then your marker is draggable

Answer (score 0):

It's because at zoom levels 1 and 2, the map has to repeat to not have blank space. The same thing happens at maps.google.com. What you can do is use zoom level 3 and 4 instead. You'll have to change your code so that the content contains more blank blue filler, but the map will no longer repeat. And the map details will still look good. Does that make sense?

Comment: Can you expand on this solution a bit? I understand that you are saying to basically make a bunch of the boundary tiles to be blue filler, but how would you do this? How would you choose which tiles are blue filler given the x,y coordinates of any given requested tile?

Answer (score 0):

There's one technique that could help, it's from this website, "Range Limiting"

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm

It's in V2, so I put together a V3 jsfiddle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/44e6y/1/

You'll see the map will not display too far away from the initial point. That is, you cannot drag the map beyond predefined limits.

However, you'll have to shrink the viewable area if you choose this method (it does nothing to the repeating markers).

Comment: That Fiddle doesn't work anymore b/c of mixed content. Updating the Maps URL to HTTPS fixes it.